# Leer fichero de texto delimitado por almohadillas en JAVA

Tags: java, csv

tengo un fichero de texto de la forma:

```
Aceite de orujo#2.11#0.21#7

Aceite girasol#5.14#0.1#3
```

Necesito leerlo y almacenar su contenido en distintas variables, es decir, hasta la primera `#` en una, hasta la segunda `#` en otra, etc.

Estoy utlizando la siguiente linea de código para leer el fichero:

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(SEPARADOR, "productos.csv");
```

Donde separador es `#`, pero no sé continuar.

Comment: cada aceite se encuentra en una línea de texto??

Comment: Si, me imagino que el salto de linea influirá a la hora de leer

Comment: Siempre van a crearse 4 variables por línea? O puede variar la cantidad de valores que pueden venir en una línea separados por el **#**?

Answer (score 1):

Si es java 8+, puedes hacerlo fácil así:

Una clase para almacenar lo que contiene cada linea, en vez de un simple array de objetos:

```
    public class Linea{
        private String campo1;
        ...
        private String campoN;
    }
```

---

El código para leer las lineas y transformarlas:

```
    private void leerFichero(Path pathAlFichero){
        List<String> lineasEnFichero = Files.readAllLines(pathAlFichero);
        List<Linea> lineas = lineasEnFichero.stream()
            .map(this::toLinea)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private Linea toLinea(String linea){
        Linea linea = new Linea();
        String valores = linea.split("#");
        linea.setCampo1(valores[0]);
        linea.setCampoN(valores[N-1]);
        return linea;
    }
```

Comment: Con tu respuesta estas asumiendo que la cantidad de variables a crear por líneas es conocida, no obstante me gusta tu enfoque en java 8 en adelante

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
public class CSVReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String csvFile = "/Users/mkyong/csv/country.csv";
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = "#";

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
                String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

                // TODO

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hola mario, mira por favor [answer]. Por mas que este codigo resuelva el problema, se pide que tambien sea explicado que hace el mismo. Se pide que las respuestas requieren la menor cantidad de clarificacion para entenderlas. saludos.